# Java generics converting Future of list of concrete class to future of list of interface?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to convert a Future of List of Concrete classes into a future of List of Interfaces, but I get an "incompatible types" error when I try it.  Basically my code looks something like this

```
public void main()
{
   Future<List<ConcreteClass>> future = getFutureStuff();
   doStuffWithInferface(future); // Syntax Error!
}

public void doStuffWithInterface(Future<List<InterfaceClass>>)
{
   blah();
}
```

Is there a good way to change this without changing the getFutureStuff signature to

```
public Future<? extends List<? extends InterfaceClass>> getFutureStuff();
```

and littering my code with ? extends InterfaceClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should do it. Suppose you have:

```
public void doStuffWithInterface(Future<List<InterfaceClass>> f)
{
   List<InterfaceClass> list = f.get();
   list.add(new AnotherConcreteClassWhichImplementsTheInterface());// it will fail if you use "? extends"
}
```

So, it makes the list of only `ConcreteClass`es to contain incompatible type.

Simple example:

```
public void addStuff(List<Number> l) {l.add(1.5);}

List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
addStuff(l);
for(Integer i : l) {}// class cast exception!
```

Comment: `list.add(subtype of Interface)` will succeed. What will fail is assigning list<SubType> to a reference of List<Interface>

Comment: After playing with it a bit, I think I get it.  The problem, from java's point of view, is the "what if someone adds the wrong type to the list later"... Ok, well that stinks because the list is immutable, but, whatever, I guess I'll start annotating the hell out of things.

Comment: @Cogman Yes, you are right. The "? extends" makes a list immutable. A little bit verbose syntax... but java always was a verbose language.

Answer (score 3):

`getFutureStuff` can stay the same but you should change the signature of `doStuffWithInterface`, since the future is being used covariantly:

```
public void doStuffWithInterface(
        final Future<? extends List<? extends InterfaceClass>> future
) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final List<? extends InterfaceClass> list = future.get();
    for (final InterfaceClass element : list) {
        //use element
    }
}

...

Future<List<ConcreteClass>> future = getFutureStuff();
doStuffWithInferface(future); // perfectly fine
```